# how to remove the messages that are being displayed on the (build,run) tab everytime I compile a C++ program in netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, build, tabs

most of the messages are useless for me and quite annoying

For example

"/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/kostas/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
"/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe
make[2]: Entering directory`/c/Users/kostas/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d
g++.exe    -c -g -I../../../../../MinGW/lib -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/kostas/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
make[1]: Leaving directory`/c/Users/kostas/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'

I don't need these things to be displayed, how to remove them completely?